# how to validate user input under 100

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to write a code where I want the total sum of all inputs to be 100. so suppose If a user enters 40% in stocks then I don't want the user to enter more than 60% in the next forex or any other input. same way if he enters 20% in forex then the sum is 60 so he won't enter more than 40% in the next two inputs (commodities and crypto). I am attaching the fiddle link in the first comment.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stock Manager</title>
</head>
<style>
    input {
        width: 30%;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <h3>Stock Manager</h3>
    <form id="myForm" action="#" onsubmit=" validateForm()">
        <label for="Stocks">Stocks</label><br>
        <input type="number" name="Stocks" id="Stocks" placeholder="Enter Stock %" min="1" max="100"><br><br>

        <label for="Forex">Forex</label><br>
        <input type="number" name="Forex" id="Forex" placeholder="Enter Forex %" min="1" max="100"><br><br>

        <label for="Commodities">Commodities</label><br>
        <input type="number" name="Commodities" id="Commodities" placeholder="Enter Commodities %" min="1"
            max="100"><br><br>

        <label for="Crypto">Crypto </label><br>
        <input type="number" name="Crypto" id="Crypto" placeholder="Enter Crypto %" min="1" max="100"><br><br>

        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>


    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

    function validateForm(e) {
    const Stocks = document.forms["myForm"]["Stocks"].value;
    const Forex = document.forms["myForm"]["Forex"].value;
    const Commodities = document.forms["myForm"]["Commodities"].value;
    const Crypto = document.forms["myForm"]["Crypto"].value;
    console.log('output', Stocks, Forex, Commodities, Crypto)
    
    const totalPercentage = 100
    

}
```

Comment: What is preventing you from even attempting this?

Comment: What have you tried? What is in main.js ?

Answer (score 0):

There are, to my mind, two tasks to this. The validating of the form upon submit and the calculation of the total sum deduced from the numbers entered.

If the form can only be submitted successfully when the sum of any/all inputs is exactly 100 then the `sum===100` is fine otherwise if it could be less than 100 change that to `sum <= 100` in the `validateform` function below.

To limit the numbers entered as the user does so is slightly more involved as you need to track all input values and derive the sum in real time - and I opted below to warn the user if the current sum exceeded 100 as you'll see in the snippet.

```js
const validateForm=(event)=>{
  let sum=0;
  Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('[type="number"]') ).forEach(input=>{
    sum+=Number( input.value );
  });
  console.log( 'Current sum: %d', sum );
  return sum===100;
};

let tx=NaN;
let obj={};

Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('[type="number"]') ).forEach( input=>input.addEventListener('input',(e)=>{
  if( !obj.hasOwnProperty(e.target.name) ) obj[e.target.name]=true;
  obj[e.target.name]=e.target.value;
  
  
  let sum=Object.values( obj ).reduce( (a,b)=>Number( a ) + Number( b ) );
  if( sum > 100 ){
    console.log('Whoah there cowboy!');
    obj[e.target.name]=0;
    warn(e.target);
    return false;
  }
}));

const warn=(n)=>{
  n.classList.add('warn');
  if( !isNaN( tx ) )clearTimeout( tx );
  tx=setTimeout(()=>{
    n.classList.remove('warn');
    n.value='';
  },1500);
}
```

```css
input{padding:0.25rem;}
.warn{background:rgba(255,0,0,0.25);border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<form method='post' onsubmit='return validateForm(event)'>
    <label for='Stocks'>Stocks
        <input type='number' name='Stocks' placeholder='Enter Stock %' min='1' max='100' />
    </label>
    
    <label for='Forex'>Forex
        <input type='number' name='Forex' placeholder='Enter Forex %' min='1' max='100' />
    </label>
    
    <label for='Commodities'>Commodities
        <input type='number' name='Commodities' placeholder='Enter Commodities %' min='1' max='100' />
    </label>
    
    <label for='Crypto'>Crypto
        <input type='number' name='Crypto' placeholder='Enter Crypto %' min='1' max='100' />
    </label>
    
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

One thing you can do. You can set interval to the function in javascript which will check all inputs based on id like this,

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById('Stocks');
  var input2 = document.getElementById('Forex');
  var input3 = document.getElementById('Commodities');
  var input4 = document.getElementById('Crypto');

  var tot = 0;
  if (input1.value != "") {
    tot = tot + parseInt(input1.value);
    if (tot > 100) {
      alert('invalid percentile sum of all fields must not be greater then 100');
      input1.value = "";
    }
    //console.log(tot);
    if (tot == 100) {
      if (input2.value == "") {
        input2.disabled = true;
      }
      if (input3.value == "") {
        input3.disabled = true;
      }
      if (input4.value == "") {
        input4.disabled = true;
      }
    } else {
      input2.disabled = false;
      input3.disabled = false;
      input4.disabled = false;
    }
  }
  if (input2.value != "") {
    tot = tot + parseInt(input2.value);
    if (tot > 100) {
      alert('invalid percentile sum of all fields must not be greater then 100');
      input2.value = "";
    }
    //console.log(tot);
    if (tot == 100) {
      if (input1.value == "") {
        input1.disabled = true;
      }
      if (input3.value == "") {
        input3.disabled = true;
      }
      if (input4.value == "") {
        input4.disabled = true;
      }
    } else {
      input1.disabled = false;
      input3.disabled = false;
      input4.disabled = false;
    }
  }
  if (input3.value != "") {
    tot = tot + parseInt(input3.value);
    if (tot > 100) {
      alert('invalid percentile sum of all fields must not be greater then 100');
      input3.value = "";
    }
    //console.log(tot);
    if (tot == 100) {
      if (input1.value == "") {
        input1.disabled = true;
      }
      if (input2.value == "") {
        input2.disabled = true;
      }
      if (input4.value == "") {
        input4.disabled = true;
      }
    } else {
      input1.disabled = false;
      input2.disabled = false;
      input4.disabled = false;
    }
  }
  if (input4.value != "") {
    tot = tot + parseInt(input4.value);
    if (tot > 100) {
      alert('invalid percentile sum of all fields must not be greater then 100');
      input4.value = "";
    }
    //console.log(tot);
    if (tot == 100) {
      if (input1.value == "") {
        input1.disabled = true;
      }
      if (input3.value == "") {
        input3.disabled = true;
      }
      if (input2.value == "") {
        input2.disabled = true;
      }
    } else {
      input1.disabled = false;
      input3.disabled = false;
      input2.disabled = false;
    }
  }
}, 1000); //here 1000 is milisec. where 1000 milisec = 1 sec, so fuction will execute every sec.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background-color: black;">

<head>
  <title>My Portfolio</title>
  <style>
    #navigation-bar {
      background-color: black;
      color: grey;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-family: Script;
      font-size: 25px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <label for="Stocks">Stocks</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="Stocks" id="Stocks" placeholder="Enter Stock %" min="1" max="100"><br><br>

    <label for="Forex">Forex</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="Forex" id="Forex" placeholder="Enter Forex %" min="1" max="100"><br><br>

    <label for="Commodities">Commodities</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="Commodities" id="Commodities" placeholder="Enter Commodities %" min="1" max="100"><br><br>

    <label for="Crypto">Crypto </label><br>
    <input type="number" name="Crypto" id="Crypto" placeholder="Enter Crypto %" min="1" max="100"><br><br>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this must be helpful to you

Comment: The web is event based. Polling is not the way to go.